# Texture not showing when loading obj, mtl in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to load a model using objloader + mtlloader as follows:

```
var mtlLoader = new THREE.MTLLoader();
                mtlLoader.setPath( '/examples/obj/rock/' );
                mtlLoader.load( 'rock.mtl', function( materials ) {
                    materials.preload();
                    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
                    objLoader.setMaterials( materials );
                    objLoader.setPath( '/examples/obj/rock/' );
                    objLoader.load( 'rock.obj', function ( object ) {
                        console.log(object);
                        object.position.y = 0;
                        scene.add( object );

                    }, onProgress, onError );

                });

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

The mesh loads correctly and I get the following result:

[image]

All of my assets for the model are stored under the same path - /examples/obj/rock.

The assets are:
- rock.obj
- rock.mtl
- rock.png

The contents of the .mtl file are as follows:

```
# Blender MTL File: 'Rock #1.blend'
# Material Count: 1

newmtl Rock-Texture
Ns 96.078431
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.720000 0.720000 0.720000
Ks 0.100000 0.100000 0.100000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
map_Kd rock.png
```

Comment: you need to provide a fiddle as the problem is not obvious with the code you posted.

Comment: Are there any errors in the JS console?

Comment: No errors, the only error I had when I just took the plain exported files was the path to the .mtl file to the texture file, because it was set to an absolute path on my machine, but once I changed it to the path relative to the mtl file, the error dissappeared

Comment: Could you solve it?